# Spring WebFlow external site callback to action-state or trigger specific event thru url

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

## Spring WebFlow 2 external site callback to `view-state` with a trigger of specific `webflow-event` which is encoded in callback-url

*Hello*, fellow coders! Please read issue below and provide your solutions/practice/insights thank you for your time and knowledge.

---

#### Definition

- `<view-state>` triggers an external-redirect thru standard
  `html-form`(`http post`).
- User performs some actions on external-application
- Knowing `_flowExecutionKey` external-site callbacks using `http-get`
  to the same  `<view-state>`.
- continue to **issue** description

---

### Issue

On comeback from external-app user should not be shown a view defined in `<view-state>`,

instead transition to `action-state` should happen without user interaction;

with request(callback) url parameters available.

How to accomplish this with spring webflow? Can programmatic approach be used on -- `<view-state>` `<on-render>` -- action to transition flow to `action-state`.

If other technique should be employed to resolve this issue - please let us know.

---

#### Observations/Restrictions

- `_eventId=someEventId` or `_eventId_someEventId`in url does not trigger spring-webflow event
- `<on-render/>` returned spring-webflow-Event does not trigger transition
- JavaScript used on rendered page to click button is not a grace solution, though working

---

Tools/Frameworks related to question-context:

- Spring WebFlow 2
- JSF 2.1

---

#### snippet of webflow defintion sample for discussion

```
<view-state
    id="redirectToExternalSiteAndComeBack"
    view="/someViewToRedirectToExternalSite.xhtml"
    redirect="true">
    <on-entry/> <!-- for illustration only, does nothing -->
    <on-render/><!-- for illustration only, does nothing -->
    <transition on="handleExternalSiteCallback" to="handleCallBack"/>
    <!-- Trigerred on button,link click -->
</view-state>
```

Answer (score 3):

Transitions from a view state do require user interactions but there's a way by which you can achieve what you want.

Suppose your use case is - at certain point in web flow let's say `e1s7` you want to go to an external site, which you could do by using externalRedirect, and then come back to the flow and execute some actions. Let say the external site is a bank which needs a callback url to take user back to your site. Here's what the bankUrl would look like for the xml snippet at bottom

```
bankUrl = https://somebank.com?callback=${callback}
${callback} = https://yoursite.com/flowPath?execution=e1s7&_eventId=process (do encode this!)
```

The flow execution key can be referenced by using something like `#{flowExecutionContext.key.toString()}`

```
<view-state id="redirectToBank" view="externalRedirect:${bankUrl}>
    <transition on="process" to="process">
</view-state>

<action-state id="process">
    ...do something...
</action-state>
```

Hope that helps.